# Who are you and who I am?

Tags: family

> You are my uncle, you are my half- brother's son.
>   I'm your uncle, I'm your half-brother's son.

**Who are you and who I am?**

Note: Relationships must be legal and agree with church marriage contract.

Comment: Can you define what it means for a relationship to be legal and to agree with the "church marriage contract"?

Comment: As in, incest is out? And are you implying heterosexual only?

Comment: Church marriage, like no divorce?

Comment: let's say I don't know you and no kinship at all between us , then i marry a woman , later i find that she is your mother , and  you are married to my devorced mother that i havn't seen  for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can start by removing unnecessary information,

> I'm your half-brother's son. => He is my uncle.
>  
>  You are my half-brother's son. => I am his uncle.

Now we just have to find some combination by which following statement hold true:

> I'm his half-brother's son.
>  
>  
>  And he's my half-brother's son.

One of the scenarios where this is possible:

> Your grandma is my mother and my grandma is your mother.

Detailed Explanation:

> Let's say my father is S and my mother is R. Let the other person in the puzzle be X, his father be Y and his mother be Z.
>
> Z was first married to my grandpa and is mother of my father S. Later she married Y, with whom she had a son X. Therefore my father and X are half-brothers and so I'm the son of X's half-brother. 
>
> Similarly, R was married to X's grandpa and is Y's mother. Later she divorced X's grandpa and married my father S. Therefore Y and me are half brothers and so X is my half-brother's son.

Comment: I believe your first two implications are reversed.

Comment: @Riley it is a puzzle , then fix it.

Comment: @benasfan Updated the answer.

Comment: Your answer is correct but the detailed explanation is also misleading, you inverted the two "therefore" part: When talking about the mother of X and S (Z) you are concluding that you and X are half brother. your conclusion should be that X and S are half brothers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is...

> My mom had a son from previous marriage (her first husband died so the church were fine with it), this person is my half brother. He had a son - you!
>  
>  Your parents abandoned you, so my grandparents adopted you, making you my uncle, and also my half-brother's son.
>  
>  I am also your half-brother's son because you're the adopted child of my grandparents. Since you're the son of my half-brother, I'm also your uncle.

Comment: I mean how did we (me and you) become relatives that way?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is correct or agreed with church marriage contract -

> 6 peoples are involved including yourself and I, say A,B,C,D,U,I:
>  
>  A, B, U and I = male, C and D = female
>  
>  A is married to C and made U, B is married to D and made I
>  
>  B is A's son and D is C's daughter.   A and C divorced, so is B and D.
>  A married D and B married C.
>  
>  Now, everything is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

> My paternal-grandmother and a man had a son, this son is my father. My father met my mother and had me as a child, but got divorced. My mother then remarried and had a child which is my half-brother. My paternal-grandmother got divorced, and met my half brother (they are not related since we share only a mother). My-half brother and my paternal grandmother had a child, which is you. Since you and my father share the same mother. You are my father's half-brother and therefore my uncle. Since your father is my half-brother, I am also your uncle

To summarize:

> Your mother is my father's mother. Your father is my mother's other son.